# wrapping extruded text and polygons around a sphere

Tags: modeling

I want to wrap some 3d text around a sphere, and also put a star that conforms to the sphere on the top.  Similar to the following image, except that both will be sticking out some.

I've found several videos that claim to do this but what they're really showing is how to wrap text around a cylinder and not a true spherical wrap.

Can anyone provide any pointers or clues?

Thanks

[image: xmas ornament]

Comment: I'd either go with a *Shrinkwrap* modifier or a *Cast* modifier.