# Text on a balloon

Tags: modeling, mesh, text-object

I want to create an image like below, so a balloon with text on it.

[image]

I have been googling for ideas (text, sphere, ....) and came on [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27571/wrapping-extruded-text-and-polygons-around-a-sphere) earlier question. So I tried Shrinkwrap and Cast modifier.

Here is the situation before applying the modifiers.

[image]

This was after trying Shrinkwrap

[image]

And this after Cast modifier.

[image]

For me it does not look like it is going to work with one of these modifiers.

**Question** How to create the image of a balloon with text on it ? With one of these modifiers or should I try a complete other approach ?? How to do this ?

Comment: The problem is with the geometry of the text.  Text objects have horrible topology by default.  Try a remesh modifier on the text before the shrinkwrap/cast.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a text object instead of simply using an image texture?

Comment: I considered an image texture but since I am really a beginner with image textures, unwrapping and uv mapping that was not the route I was thinking of. But I certainly want to learn. Maybe it is less complicated than I think it is

Comment: In that case I will add an answer for both and you can see which you prefer.

Comment: one of my "challenges" is that a balloon is more complicated than a UV sphere

Comment: What is the geometry of the balloon like?

Comment: My answer used a UV sphere but it should work fine with your mesh as well.

Comment: after playing with both methods I think the Image Texture approach is the preferred route

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem with the Shrinkwrap modifier is that it requires decently even topology, and text objects have horrendously miserable topology.

Here is a text object with wire shown.  All those long skinny tris make for terrible deformation.

[image]

To fix this first convert your object to a mesh (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and add solidify it slightly (because Remesh needs a 3D solid object, you can delete the solidification later).  Then add a *Remesh* modifier and knock up the *Octree Depth* until the detail looks good (I used a value of `6`).  Also be sure to uncheck *Remove Disconnected Pieces*.

[image]
<sub>*Click to enlarge.*</sub>

Then you can apply the Remesh modifier and go into edit mode and delete the second layer of vertices to make it 2D again.  You can then apply the *Cast* and *Shrinkwrap* modifiers.  It should deform much better this time.

[image]

Here are a few pointers and tips:

- Put the *Cast* modifier above the *Shrinkwrap* modifier in the stack.
- Be sure to set the *Control Object* of the Cast modifier to the sphere/balloon.  And make sure that the origin of the balloon is at the center of spherical part.
- The closer the text object is to the surface of the balloon the better.

Comment: I think you did not extrude the text before converting to a mesh, right ?

Comment: @JanScherders  Yes, I converted it to a mesh, solidified, then added the Remesh modifier.  I solidified it in edit mode with [Ctrl]+[F] > *Solidify*.  I am working on the texture solution right now too.

Comment: would it be different if you first extrude, then converted to a mesh and then would do no solidify ?

Comment: @JanScherders  No, I didn't think of that.  That should work fine.

Comment: I now also tried this method. I first added Solidify and then Remesh. When I apply the Remesh modifier the text object disappears and Blender says "applied modifier was not first and result may not be as aspected". When I undo this and try to move up the Remesh modifier my text object disappears again ?

Comment: @JanScherders  I actually didn't use a soldify modifier (though you could, just apply it before the remesh).  I wen't into edit mode, and hit [Ctrl]+[F] > *Solidify*.

Answer (score 10):

If you are just trying to put text on a balloon, I would use a texture, not a text mesh.

To unwrap the balloon, I "cheated" and just marked seams around where the text was to be placed, the rest doesn't matter since you aren't putting any text on it.  Then after unwrapping I just scaled the rest of the pelt down and put it in the corner and made the important part fill the UV tile.

[image]

Then I exproted the UV layout (UV/Image Editor > UVs > *Export UV Layout*) and used it as a foreground image in GIMP to create this image to use as a mask on the balloon.

[image]

Then you can plug this image into the *fac* of a *Mix RGB* node with the two colors of the balloon.  White areas of the mask will get the second color and black areas will get the first color.  Then plug that into the color of your shader[s].

[image]

Here's a render:

[image]

Comment: I managed to find out how to add the Image Texture to my existing Node tree. Thanks a lot for your help !!! You really made me understand how to solve this kind of issues :)