# Wave deformities

Tags: text-object, dynamic-paint

I'm adding the wave dynamic paint to the roman numerals XX, but the waves are shapes very peculiar, is there a way to fix this?, if so, what will it look as bad fully rendered? [image: EAST Project]

Comment: Text objects have *terrible* topology, you need some nice even topology for any type of deformation.  See my answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39566/5705).

Comment: A grid-shaped topology like PGmath suggested would definitely be an improvement. I think insetting will give you the best results though. [See this.](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?374883-quad-mesh-fill-SVG-to-Mesh-Curve-To-Mesh-objects)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I used re-mesh to give the text objects more topology.