# better Curve/Text to Mesh generation?

Tags: mesh, particles, bezier-curves, text-object

The triangulation process of Text to Mesh or Curve to Mesh generates some nasty topology.
[image]

I get why, but maybe it could be done a bit nicer? Since text is flat, have ngons instead of hundreds of triangles you'll need to modify anyway?

Another issue is when you then want to use the text as a Volume for particles, which for some reason behave weird when you have unusual topology even though they should be using the volume, not vertex or face positions.

[image]

Comment: See my answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39566/5705).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to Remesh text. You'll be converting to a Mesh anyway if you want to add particles, so what you might do is:

- extrude the Text object ( in the properties panel )
- Add Remesh Modifier with appropriate settings, usually you need a low threshold.
  [image]
- Convert to Mesh: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Object Mode -> *Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text* , this will apply the Remesh Modifier too
  and you'll get this:
  [image]

Comment: Also, you can first add a solidfy modifier before the remesh so that you needn't convert the text to a mesh before applying the remesh modifier. This allows you to keep the text editable, and if the simple deform modifiers are all you need to apply to the text (i.e. no proportional editing, weight editing etc.) then everything remains quite flexible.