# How can I create text with a neat quad topology for deformation?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, text-object

I was trying to do a simple text warp effect in Photoshop and the built-in effects didn't give me the exact shape I wanted, so I decided to give it a shot in Blender. **Blender's versatility allowed me to easily warp and scale the text, but the problem is that the text mesh I created had extremely poor topology which doesn't deform well.** Ideally, I would like to have a very even quad topology.

I can create the desired topology manually using the steps shown in the image below:

[image: a]

This allows me to use proportional editing lattice or bend modifier and get a clean deformation. However, this is quite time-consuming, so I was wondering if there is a simple function that will allow me to get a result similar to that shown in step 3. but a bit more automated to save time and allow iteration if I need to change the text? Basically, I need something like the dynamesh remesh feature of zbrush that takes an input mesh and slices it into an even grid. Does this exist in Blender?

Comment: Result on the bottom of screenshot can be achieved with Remesh modifier (if extruding text a bit outwards as Remesh doesn't work with infintely thin planes). However this geometry won't be good for any deformation such as Subsurf or alike

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise that someone had already asked this question, and I also didn't try experimenting enough with remesh until after I posted the question. I will add another answer to the original question, as it seems worth mentioning that you can also use the solidfy modifier to keep the text editable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sup>Didn't realize this was [a duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/42571/30849).</sup>

To expand on MrZak's comment.

A similiar geometry can be created with the help of the [Remesh modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html).

1. Raise the **Extrude** property of the text to > 0.
2. Add a remesh modifier. Uncheck **Remove Disconnected Pieces**. Raise the octree depth untill the result becomes acceptable.
3. In the 3D view, press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and choose *convert to mesh*. (You now have polygon geometry.)
4. In edit mode, remove half of the text to make a flat solid again.

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for the gif.