# How would I make this A into an n-gon?

Tags: modeling

I just have this "a" mesh, I fixed it up after i turned the text into a mesh, and I don't know how to dissolve these edge loops to make the top and bottom face an ngon since I don't need it to have nice geo. And I can't actually dissolve them, so I'm confused. also I can't just select the entire outside and fill a face because it fills over the hole in the a. Thanks for the help.
[image]

Comment: Because blender's algorithms can't describe a face with a (unconnected) "hole" in it, edges like this are necessary for areas such as the "hole" in your A - You can move them to have nicer placement, but you cannot remove  them.

Comment: You can't make it into a single n-gon, but you can partition it into several n-gons. fill in an edge wherever there are forks in the path - around the center hole, for example. In this case 5 or 6 edges should be enough. Then fill in the n-gon faces. Just beware that n-gons do not deform well. But that's [another topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42571/).