# How can I project text around a sphere using shrinkwrap modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]
 text object doesn't project correctly to my mesh sphere, and often (but not always) blender crashes when I try "Mode project".
I can't get the text to wrap correctly around the mesh.
So, why doesn't "project mode" Do anything? (except crashing blender) - When i am able to apply it, nothing happens.
[image]

Thanks in advance, / Dan

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more info. It's not clear what you are asking. Show us some screenshots and reference images of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: ok, updated... does that make more sense? =) can you help me fix the problem? - i still didn't solve this. thanks..

Comment: Curve objects alone don't work well with the shrinkwrap modifier, it can only project correctly the border vertex, but since the "text fill" has no subdivisions it has no geometry, so can't  be projected as expected. You will probably have to finish your text object first, then convert to mesh, subdivide it manually, and only then shrinkwrap. If blender crashes you should report a bug with the file attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this Blend file: [image]

For the Shwinkwrap modifier to generate a smooth result in a situation like this, more geometry is needed. You need to subdivide the Text Object first to provide the necessary detail. Luckily, this can be done dynamically using modifiers:

Setup a Subsurf Modifier on the Text object. Set its mode to **Simple** instead of Catmull-Clark to avoid distorting your Text object. Subdivide as many times as needed, but try to stay on the lower end (I chose 2 for Display and render):

[image: before wrapping]

Now, to use **Projected** as a mode, you'll need to setup the Axis correctly as well as which direction Blender is supposed to look for the other object to wrap on: I chose my sphere as a Target, then set the Axis using the check boxes (note that for the modifier the **LOCAL** Axis of the object counts. In the first screenshot you can see that the blue arrow correlates with the direction I want to go in, so that's the Z direction). The direction field now lets you choose the direction in which Blender looks for the Sphere. Again, look at the first screenshot: the Blue Arrow points AWAY from the sphere. That means, to make the Text wrap towards it, the Direction needs to be set to 'negative'.

[image: after wrapping]

Comment: Note that using the Shrinkwrap modifier will make your text be at the same plane as the geometry you wrap it around to, yielding possible Z-Fighting issues. Try to separate the text a bit using the **offset** option on the modifier.

Comment: An alternative way to do this (specially if the text has some extrusion) is to use a lattice and have the lattice deform the text and use the shrinkwrap modifier on the lattice: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface/44820#44820