# How to deform a plane according to the shape of other objects

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I have 2 planes: 1 with Displace modifier (so random hills and valleys according to a cloud texture) and another flat of different size. My question is if it is possible to deform the flat plane according to the first plane.

Depending on where I place the second plane regarding the first plane it'll take exactly the same shape the first one has at the position where I place it. Think of the second plane like a piece of cloth that when I put it on top of a rough surface, depending on where in the other surface, it would deform and take the shape of the irregularities it is placed on.

Comment: Either Lattice modifier added to the second plane together with Shrinkwrap modifier so Shrinkwrap will stick the lattice to the plane, and second plane will follow lattice or add a Cloth modifier on second plane and run animation. Note - all possible solutions here most likely will depend on the geometry (should be pretty high).

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface

Comment: Thanks for the reply and edit. I followed the lattice on the given link, but the 2nd plane just got stick to the first without deformation. I tried to change lattice U, V, and it got even weirder shape. Maybe the geometry is not high enough?

Comment: Probably, not enough geometry might cause that, though It's hard to tell without screenshots.

Comment: I think in this case, the lattice is not needed and may keep the plane flat. Try to shrinkwrap directly without lattice (but with enough geometry for the plane)

Comment: I can do Shrinkwarp to the first plane, i.e. deform the first plane to attach to the flat one, but not the other way around. Maybe I did not know how?

Comment: You should edit your question in order to show what you obtain, what is wrong and how is your setup (modifiers or others)

Answer (score 1):

If the base terrain plane is deformed by a displace modifier why not just give the second plane the same modifier stack?

If I understand correctly this is the effect you are aiming for, kind of like a manta-ray wavy hover motion

[image: Hover]

Just add a second plane above the first one, subdivide it accordingly, and link the modifiers to the original one. Select new plane > select terrain > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> *Modifiers*.

Make sure both objects have the same displace modifier or most importantly share **the same displace texture** and with the both *Texture Coordinates* set to *Global*

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is just what I want, with a little modification. I didn't think it would be that hard when I see your answer. The problem is the second plane has it own Displace, of another different terrain type. I would just overlay one on the other so that I can have different type of terrains on my landscape. But as you say they must have the same modifier stack, I guess, I cannot go this way?!

Comment: BTW, do you think there're not really fit, the corners of your blue plane, to the white plane?

Comment: Sorry, but to me the two shapes are not in phase... am I wrong? I still think that a shrinkwrap (negative and project) is better for the blue plane

Comment: @AugLe The modifier stack doesn't have to be exactly the same, it only has to use the **same cloud texture** on a *Displace modifier* set to Global. You may even have additional *Displace* modifiers on the plane if you so wish, as long the one of them uses the same terrain cloud texture.

Comment: @lemon now that you mention it they may net be *exactly* in sync since the cloud texture is a "volumetric" "3D function", and the plane is offset in Z yielding slightly different displace. The closer they are however, the more in sync they should be though, I just offset them for clarity purposes here. In anyway, a *Shrinkwrap* would also work well here too.