# How to fix the eyes with shrinkwrap

Tags: modifiers

I have made the face and i want to shrinkwrap the eyes on the face. I have tried all the options in the shrinkwrap but did not get success. I tried the project option but fail to shrinkwrap on the face. Any suggestion or help thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is due to the geometry: this is not (easily) shrinkable. You should see this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface/44820#44820

Comment: @lemon so i have to recreate the mesh (eyes) or is there any option. Is that due to high subsurface

Comment: No you don't have to if you use the lattice technics indicated in the link. Concerning the shrinkwrap: it will either flatten or concern the faces depending on their normals. The only trick to be used directly is to use vertex groups (but it may be painful in the case of this mesh). Try the lattice, adjust and that may do the job

Comment: I won't provide an answer (your question is nearly a duplicate of the link above) but just so you can see that it is working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVuND.gif