# Want to shape this spiderman lens around the Faceshell so it fits perfectly against the shell

Tags: 3d-printing

Was wondering if someone can help me. I want ti be able to bend this lens around the spiderman faceshell so that it sits flush with the shell. I have tried shrinkwrap and adding depth after but it looks horrible. Any ideas please?

Thanks

[image][image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77277/how-to-fix-the-eyes-with-shrinkwrap and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89300/why-is-shape-with-shrinkwrap-modifier-flat and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95975/why-im-not-getting-thickness-with-shrinkwrap-modifier

Answer (score 0):

You could scale the lens shape up on the y(?) axis to make it like a tube, move it so that it crosses the faceshell where you want it, then put a boolean modifier (subtract) on it so that it has one side flush fit. Next, delete all the other faces, then extrude what you have left to the desired thickness.

Comment: Thanks for all the great suggestions guys. I tried the lattice and shrink wrap method and i got it pretty close but its still not flat againt the faceshell and loses some of the frames depth too