# How can I bend a mesh so that it curves around other object?

Tags: modifiers

I have base of the machine and the button separate model. I want the button to be bend and shrink so that it fix on the top of the machine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried shrinkwrap and bend option but its not working.

**With bend option i got this result**

[image]

**With shrinkwrap option i got this result**

[image]

I want to achieve this result

[image]

Comment: The shrinkwrap modifier is going to flatten your object. Use a lattice to deform the buttons and then shrinkwrap the lattice over the other object. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44820/1853

Comment: @cegaton do i have to apply the lattice to proceed with the shrikwrap modifier

Comment: Please read the link.

Comment: @cegaton it not working for me this is my result. http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=123045

Comment: You would need to rotate the buttons element so that is parallel to the floor. Then use a lattice with only one subdivision on the Z axis, place it at the bottom of the buttons object. Then shrinkwrap would work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

As you correctly guessed, you can use the `simple deform` modifier, with the `bend` option. However, you have to change the direction and origin of the bend You can control this by creating an `empty` and positioning it close to the button, if you select the empty in the `origin` property of the modifier. Here, I created two deform modifiers, controlled by two empties:
[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

The two empties were made the children of the button, and rotated so that the bending happened in the right direction (to find the right direction, I had to play with the rotation a bit - there is no easy way to understand the correct orientation):

[image: Rotate]

The modifiers look like this (again, I had to try different angles to find a good value):

[image: Modifiers]

Here is the `.blend` file:

[image]

Comment: Looks good what i need but at the bottom its not touching the base. Some gap space seen. Other that its perfect. http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=123044

Comment: @atek, to fix that, you'll just have to move it along the z-axis (`G` for grab + `Z` for locking on z-axis, hold `Shift` for more accurate movement), and maybe tweak the `angle`s a little bit, until you get the effect you want. Good luck! :)

Comment: @atek to get "perfect result" is perhaps better to fit your "control panel" into an  "inset"of the machine body, as it probably is in reality. And, I would also model the panel itself from a copy of the destination curved surface.