# Wrapping a flat object around a cylinder and joining it

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a nanotube model and while I can get the flat structure to loop around a circle, I'm not sure how to join the ends of it into a complete structure. I started with the flat structure and am now trying to revolve it.[image]
[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98957/bend-a-honeycomb-mesh

Comment: Give it a curve modifier, targeting a bezier circle object, then scale the curve to eye until the mesh is right.  With a file, I could give more complete instructions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way I can think of to achieve your goal. However, I think it would work if you set your array modifier to object offset and then select an empty of your choice. By moving and rotating the empty, it should give you more control to find the best position.

I doubt it would work, but the Shrink wrap modifier might also be able to solve your problem. If you want, I'm willing to look at your file and see what I can do.

Comment: Sure how can I attach a file?

Comment: If you still need my help, you can zip the file and share a Google Drive link with me. That's what I do, but if you feel that threatens your privacy, that's reasonable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Tessellate tool out? Maybe that could work. There is a tutorial here that explains how to use the Tessallate to, to make a geometric structure out of a simple model you've made:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tce6GqNyJ2A

Hope this can help you achieve what you are looking for.