# How to wrap and boolean around a cylinder?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am relatively new to Blender. I have faced the challenge during modeling a microphone. There is a specific pattern of grid that looks like a honeycomb. Actually, it was quite easy to create that pattern by using a circle. Then I applied a solidify modifier in order to create a volume. And I reached the point of wraping this grid around the main cylinder and putting holes in it. I tried couple of ways to make it happen by using Shrinkwrap modifier, Lattice, Surface deform, but the result was unsatisfactory. Does someone know another way to make the holes around the microphone? Thank you[image]

Comment: @JachymMichal I think you already covered this topic, right?

Comment: Enable addon "Extra Mesh", it contains "Honey Comb" object. Create pattern of desired dimension and wrap arround with "Simple Deform" or "Curve modifier". With your current technique you will deal with bad Boolean topology. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/99052/2214

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *Curve* modifier to make your pattern turn around. Don't forget to put the honeycomb object at the exact same position as the bezier circle origin (use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> for a *Cursor to Selected* then *Selected to Cursor*).

[image]

You could also use the *Simple Deform* modifier with *Bend* option. These methods will slightly deform each cylinder of the honeycomb object though, if you don't want that use another method like for example array around an empty (i.e. *Array* modifier with the *Object Offset* option)