# SVG file with curve modifier possible with curves?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, svg

I would like to edit my imported SVG file with a Curve Modifier. However, the bottom line of my g does not match the rounding of the circle and on closer inspection this problem occurs with every letter. Unfortunately the problem cannot be solved by adding more curve points to the file or by increasing the resolution of the curve file. My question now would be whether there is a possibility to easily adapt the SVG file to a circle without having to convert it to a mesh? Attached you'll find the blender file v2.79b - https://we.tl/t-7ijI7Ads1S
[image][image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface

Comment: When doing deformations with curves it matters that the origin is placed at the center of the objects, and that the origins of both objects is in the same place in the 3D world.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thx for the link. Unfortunately my problem at the letter g remains the same (updated a screenshot).

Comment: @cegaton moving the origin had no influence on the behavior of the curve.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve this if your logo is a curve, I guess you need to convert it to a mesh, so:

- Delete the *Curve* modifier.
- Convert your curve to mesh with an <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Mesh from Curve*.
- To clean your mesh, go in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve*.
- Now as your mesh is supposed to bend you need to give it back a higher topology, you'll use the *Remesh* modifier (maybe there's a better way though).
- Extrude your mesh with <kbd>E</kbd>.
- Give it the *Remesh* modifier with *Octree Depth* > 8 and deactivate *Remove Disconnected Pieces*.
- Apply the modifier. Now you have a high poly. Only keep the top surface.
- You can give your object a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Object*. It works.

[image]