# fill unconnected bezier curves with smooth shapes to create mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves, svg

Using Adobe IIustrator, we created svg from png file.
Once we imported [svg](https://fashion-desings.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/common/casuals/tshirts/userchoice/glass51.svg) into blender we found disconnected Bezier curves.

this seems to be long pending issue with blender..

[image]

Initially we tried by connecting all the curves using ctrl-J and fill it some shapes but no luck..

we tried with this [approach](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134714/svg-file-with-curve-modifier-possible-with-curves) but unable to fix it...

tried with below links as well...

[How fill face between irregular curves?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18177/how-fill-face-between-irregular-curves)

[Curves wrong filled when importing svg](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46639/curves-wrong-filled-when-importing-svg)

guys can somebody throw some light here....

Thanks

vijay