# Asking for help regarding usage of Shrinkwrap, Surface deform and Snap

Tags: subdivision-surface, parent, snapping, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to follow this tutorial on how to deform my object relative to targeted surface.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luFz5gzvM9s&fbclid=IwAR0Tz5l0c7qzUIODeuzgJXOrPc1Au1PT_Ua9ljzw-HazFN-GJrQo9D5eFFM

I can't seem to do it the same way, I tried to follow every single step but the object doesn't deform the way I wanted to.

Here I attached my blender file to see how it looks like and so you can spot my mistakes.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use blend-exchange if you want to provide files for us to check. Random file sharing services won't keep them up long enough.

Comment: Finally solved it. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface Thank you guys!