# Matching a Mesh curve to another Mesh curve keeping height?

Tags: mesh

Just wondering if there is an easy way to have this mesh match the curve of the other mesh under it without losing its height? I've fiddled with a few modifiers but I can't quite get it to do what I want. Is there a tool I can use or am I better off trying a different approach?

Cheers. :)

Also if you can't tell from this angle, that shape is a hollow circle covered in a steel grill pattern. I need to whole lot to bend to match the shape under it while maintaining its shape and dimensions if possible. :/

[image]

Comment: Try using a curve modifier. You can duplicate an edge of the bottom meshand seperate it by selection. After that you can convert that edge into a curve and then enter that curve in the curve modifier of your top object.

Comment: That combined with some other fiddling got it to work! :) Thank you for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome (:

Comment: There are quite a few answers here which use [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44820/35559)