# Text on round surface (mug)

Tags: modeling, text-object

I want to write a simple text on a mug, but can't figure out how, I tried using a lattice and shrink wrapping but it was all jumbled up. That was that only method I found... so i'm guessing it should be something very obvious(?)

**EDIT:** So the text follows the surface nicely with the **curve modifier**, and I found out what I messed up with **lattice modifier** too *(thanks to JakeD)*, however there is a small gap between the mug and the text and it is casting a shadow.
If I move it any closer the mug will hide it here and there.

I kinda wanted to avoid it and only use materials for it, but I guess they way I should do it is to put a transparent texture which contains text I assume? *(or something like that)*

[image: ref]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emboss text onto curved surface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface)

Comment: [Removing artefacts caused by too little geometric details.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39566/30849)

Comment: @Leander Related, but this question doesn't involve embossing like the one and has a simpler, different solution if the mug is cylindrical.

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean by "only materials", there are 2 ways to make text on the surface: model and curve the text as the in linked answer and optionally shrinkwrap it onto the mug OR fake it with a texture which should have transparency everywhere but areas where text is. The latter will be "with materials only" since you'll be using Node editor to create that text.

Comment: I meant only materials as in not touching textures and UV maps. 
The shrink wrapping didn't quite work out because if the text touched the mug then many parts of it got inside the mug while other parts sticked out of it, and I guess it still would've casted a shadow.

Comment: Use an image for the text and use that to control the mix between materials or shaders https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material

Comment: Anyone here could pretty easily tell you how to unwrap a mug if you had the image of the mug and text prepared. If so, just respond to me. This would fix the shadow and parallax and just make it look like ink or paint.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a [curve deform modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/curve.html):

[image]

[image]

Make sure that the origin of the curve is at the same position as that of the object you are wanting to deform...this will make it go much more smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I unwrapped the part I wanted to mess with, made the text in GIMP with a transparent background, then put it in with an Image Texture and Mix node connected to a Diffuse.

I had a feeling this would be the solution, but I wanted to be lazy and only use materials... :)