# Bending Logo to Cylinder

Tags: mesh, svg

Okay I have been through these forums for days and I'm finally breaking to ask the question.

I'm designing for 3D printing (so solid forms are extremely valuable).

I have an SVG Logo (both in Curve and Mesh format in my scene) that I need to mesh to a cylinder type shape I created so that it can be embossed onto it and then also etched into it (need to create both versions). The etched version I need to retain the inset shape so that it can be printed separately (in another color) and then glued into the etch if possible.

I've tried Shrink Wrap (makes it flush), Simple Deform (does nothing or warps it out of recognition), and Curve (if it even lets me use it) does nothing that I can tell.

I have no clue how to get this to just match the curve of the cylinder and it should not be this complicated >.<

Any help is greatly appreciated and I apologize for being such a newb.

Notes: I'm working on a Mac version of the program so the common hot key commands do not work most of the time so please avoid them in your help if possible.

I've posted two pics of my current workspace.

Again,
Thank you![[image: Program Screenshot][1]]

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify what you mean by "makes it flush" in reference to the shrinkwrap modifier?

Comment: It doesn't bevel out or recess (emboss) inward. It just becomes flush with the outside edge so if I print that, you would never know its there.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107019/text-on-round-surface-mug

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48823/deform-object-after-another-object/48841#48841

Comment: @susu That gets me really really close except there's no where I can see to set the lattice subdivisions Here's a screen shot of the lattice on load (yes I know I have to move it etc) https://ibb.co/DCtpHfG

Comment: @GrumpyHarley don't crop the images to tight, the controls for the lattice are here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRqM6.png

Comment: @susu Thank you so much for that picture! That helped and it worked!