# How to properly apply text to a sphere

Tags: text-object

I'm trying to apply text to a basic sphere but I can't figure it out. I've applied a shrinkwrap modifier to the text, and have the target of the modifier be the sphere, but the effect doesn't come out the way I want it to. The text hovers slightly in front of the sphere and part of the text doesn't look like the way it should (bottom half of the "O".)

The only way the text looks like the way I want it to is when I increase the offset setting in the shrinkwrap modifier. But then I have a problem where the text is too far away from the sphere. I want the text to look like it's a part of the sphere, sort of like a golf ball.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text on a balloon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39565/text-on-a-balloon). Many question here about that. Try searching for "shrinkwrap" and you will get a handful of answers.

Comment: For that you don't need to use shrinkwrap, just use a texture. Generate a text with alpha channel in your favorite image editing app, and create a  material that uses the texture. Read: [add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46447/1853)

Comment: If you "must" do it with shrinkwrap then read this as well: [Emboss text onto curved surface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface)