# Text Engraving on a curved surface of a subdivision model, impossible?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

EDIT: The baloon thread does not answer the question, as there it is not an answer re how to engrave with subd. One answer is a rendered solution the other answer doesnt engrave text on a subd model.

I think I have found something thats impossible to do in blender. I want to engrave a puck shape, where the engraving length is about 1/3 of the circumference of the puck. **Now here is the tricky part:** The model has to be a geometry light SUBD model (i.e. the subdivision modifier isnt applied yet). This has to be done without distorting the curvture or smoothness of the surface of the puck.

On a flat surface it would be easy. On a curved surface it seems impossible, as you need edge loops around the edges of the lettering, to sharpen them up, but that distorts the surface of the puck.

If anyone knows how to achieve a perfectly smooth (no distortions) engraving on a geometry light subd curved model as described, let me know. Seems impossible!
[image: Puck radius: 6 height: 4 Font: Inter Extra Bold Italic]

**Puck radius: 6 height: 4 Font: Inter Extra Bold Italic**

Comment: Hi :). shouldn't be that hard. I'd try creases instead of edgeloops, and cast modifier to keep the puck shape :))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text on a balloon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39565/text-on-a-balloon)

Comment: It is hard. Try it first before saying its not hard. :D Also text on a baloon thread doesnt address engraving on a subd model as described. One answer is a rendered solution. The other answer doesnt even try to engrave.

Comment: To engrave an object, you could use the Boolean modifier... To wrap the text around your object, you should use the shrinkwrap modifier (as in the Ballon answers)

Comment: Hello Emir, sadly that does not work without distortions.

Comment: Curious as to why  the model needs sub-d at all?