How do I emboss a SVG/ TIFF file onto a curved surface?
I'm trying to emboss a logo onto a curved surface and I would ideally use text but I dont have the font for this particular text. In the case of debossing, I used Boolean modifier but as far as I know, this cannot be used to emboss.

On the left is what I have and on the right is what I want.
This is where I got the SVG file: https://worldvectorlogo.com/logo/fenty-beauty (I had to edit out beauty)
I tried using the displacement modifier but got some strange results. What would be the easiest way to get the result on the right? I was looking for a way to use nodes but willing to try whichever method is efficient/ easy.

Hello, does it really need to be in volume? Can't it be a normal or bump map?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/how-to-add-curve-modifier-to-text/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39565/text-on-a-balloon

You could fake the relief with a normal or bump map. If you want to create real relief, import your svg, convert to mesh, simplify the topology with a X > Limited Dissolve:

Create a plane, subdivide it to make a grid, remove the face, put it in front of your logo object, select the logo object, switch to Edit mode, select the grid with CtrlLMB and Mesh > Knife Project:

Now you have a topology that is bendable:

Extrude it, bend it with a Simple Deform in Bend mode on Z:

Add a cylinder:


This is not really a big part of the model and may or may not be visible. Thank you, I will give this a try!

Thank you! I was able to get the desired result using the Knife project method. Thank you for the clear instructions as always!

You're welcome........   ;)
